# Let $f: [0, + \infty ) \to [0,1)$ $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}$. Find the inverse map $f^{-1}: [0,1) \to [0, + \infty )$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f: [0, + \infty ) \to [0,1)$
$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}$$

Show that

i) $f$ is strictly increasing and surjective.

ii) Find the inverse map $f^{-1}: [0,1) \to [0, + \infty )$

---

i) To be strictly increasing, we must have that the derivative is always positive. Using https://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=x%5E2%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29
we find that the derivative is
$$\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

This function will always be positive in the domain $[0, + \infty )$. So the function is strictly increasing.

For surjective, we need to solve $\frac{x^2}{1 + x^2} = y$. We get $x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{y}{1-y}}$. We have $y \in [0,1)$ so there is no risk to divide by zero or have a negative result under the square root.

I'm a bit unsure for the inverse map, isn't that the same as finding the surjective function ? Why would they ask us to do that if it's the same thing ??

Comment: Drop the minus sign in front of the square root, as the original $\;f\;$ is a positive function from all the non-negative reals. The rest is fine. You'd use the minus sign if you'd have $\;f:(-\infty,0]\to [0,1)\;$...

Comment: @DonAntonio What about the inverse map ? Is it the same as the surjective function ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but finding an inverse map automatically makes the original function bijective, meaning: injective and surjective. CHeck this.

Comment: @DonAntonio So actually in my post i did not directly prove that it’s surjective, but rather that an inverse function exists which automatically shows that it’s injective and surjective ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Feel free to post an answer if you want so I can accept it, so the question doesn’t appear in the unanswered section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not need to find the inverse map to show that it is surjective.

For example, you can do the following:

- Note that $0 \le \frac{x^2}{x^2+1}<1$.
- After showing that it is increasing, note that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=1$, by continuity, every $y \in [0, 1)$ has a preimage. Hence it is surjective.

For the preimage function,  since the preimage is nonnegative, $x = \sqrt{\frac{y}{1-y}}.$